# Excel multi-criteria CountIf for whole table

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences in a table based on two criteria. The formula below seems to work when I change the second criteria range from F3:S7 to one column F3:F7. I tried to create a dim range and set the range for the are and sub it into the formula, but that doesn't work either. How can I get the second criteria to accept a range of several columns instead of one?

```
Sub Count_number_of_occurrences_with_multiple_criteria()

'declare a variable

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("CountPrep2 (2)")

'count the number of occurrences with two criteria

ws.Range("B10") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("B3:B7"), ws.Range("B9"), ws.Range("F3:S7"), ws.Range("A10"))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft documentation about [CountIfs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842), each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns as Range1.

My suggestion would be to recreate the effect of checking the criteria using For Loops that cycle though the desired ranges. Like so:

```
Sub Count_number_of_occurrences_with_multiple_criteria()

    'declare a variable
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, _
        rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, _
        r1Cell As Range, r2Cell As Range, _
        counter As Integer
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("CountPrep2 (2)")
    
    Set rng1 = ws.Range("B3:B7")
    Set rng2 = ws.Range("F3:S7")
    
    For Each r1Cell In rng1
        If r1Cell = ws.Range("B9") Then
            For Each r2Cell In rng2
                If r2Cell = ws.Range("A10") Then
                    counter = counter + 1
                End If
            Next r2Cell
        End If
    Next r1Cell
    'count the number of occurrences with two criteria
    
    MsgBox counter
End Sub
```

Note: I don't know the specifics of your data or file format so the method by which I check the criteria likely does not accurately count the number of occurrences. This is just an example of how you might achieve your desired results.

Comment: Thank you Toddleson. Yes, it's adding up kind of funny. My original table has a column with a location (criteria 1) and several columns with answer to questions like yes, no, n/a, etc. (criteria 2). E.g. I'm trying to count the number of 'yes' in the table for location 1, and it's reading the location and answer criteria from b9 and a10. I'm using a normal Excel worksheet. If I count the number of rows and columns, would I be able to use something more similar to my original formula in a loop format substituting the rows and columns with something like (C[3]) instead of range("F3:F7")?